# How to configure hibernate UUIDGenerator to return String value instead of UUID Object

Tags: oracle, hibernate, uuid

I might be missing something very basic. I am trying to migrate from GUIDGenerator to UUIDGenerator. Our database is Oracle and the ID column is defined as Raw(16). When I define the id property as UUID object, the code works fine but the problem is that all our downstream code assumes that id is String. We can't change the type of id at this point in project. The documentation for UUID generator mentions following:

"An IdentifierGenerator which generates UUID values using a pluggable generation strategy. The values this generator can return include UUID, String and byte[16]"

But I wasn't able to find an example which shows how to configure this generator to return a String value. It always seems to return a UUID object.

I am using following in my configuration. It works i.e. it generates the string but it generates an invalid HEX string leading to Oracle Error below.

```
            @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2",
       parameters= {@Parameter(name="Type",value="StringType")})
    @Column(name="ID",columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Oracle Error:

```
         INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl -     HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
         WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1465, SQLState: 72000
        ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

Any ideas on how to generate a proper hex number using the UUIDGenerator?

Comment: Does anyone has any other ideas or do we just go with UUID object instead of String?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "ID")
private String id;

public String getId()
{
  return id;
}

public void setId(String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: We tried that but it doesn't generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID. we get following warning: 

WARN : org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator - HHH000409: Using org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator which does not generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID values; consider using org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead